# assert not caught by except block during library initialization

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, pinvoke, delphi-xe2

### Update

Further investigation showed that the assertions wasn't firing using the Delphi host because of some incorrect configuration files. Once that was solved, the Delphi host died just as dramatically as the C# host.

Please note that all this is tied to XE2 64 bit builds. We already noticed that assertions kill the Delphi 64 bit debugger, while they do not using the 32 bit platform.

Replacing the `AssertErrorProc` and just doing some logging there remedies the situation, both for the Delphi debugger as our C# and Delphi hosts.

Both hosts also survive throwing exceptions at the place of the assertions. The exceptions *are* caught by the except blocks that are in place.

The problem isn't reproducible using Delphi XE3 (thanks @David for helping out on this), so the current status is that this is tied to the (buggy) exception/assertion handling in Delphi XE2, especially on the 64 bit platform.

---

I have a Delphi DLL which is meant to be called from a self-hosted C# web-service. For debugging purposes this DLL can also be called from a Delphi executable.

The DLL can be and has been used successfully from both the Delphi and C# hosts.

Today I ran into the situation of triggering an assertion in the code executed when the DLL is initialized and found that the assertion is successfully prevented from leaving the DLL when hosted by a Delphi process, but is not caught and causes the host to die when that is a C# process.

### Delphi DLL

The Delphi DLL has its own DllProc procedure which is called manually from the dpr because the Delphi RTL "hijacks" the entry point to allow for unit initialization. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/System.DLLProc for details.

Delphi DLL dpr code:

```
begin
  DllProc := MyDllMain;
  MyDllMain(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end.
```

The custom dll main procedure simply ensures that some structures are initialized when the DLL is first loaded and are finalized when the last "loader" leaves.

```
procedure MyDllMain(Reason: Integer);
begin
  // ...
  //  DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      begin
        if _RefCount < 1 then
          InitializeDLL;

        Inc(_RefCount);
      end;
  // ...
end;
```

The InitializeDLL procedure is protected with a try except block, specifically meant to prevent exceptions escaping the DLL.

```
procedure InitializeDLL;
begin
  try
    // Some code triggering an Assert(False, 'Whatever');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      TLogger.LogException('InitializeDLL');
    // Don't raise through. Exceptions should not leave DLL.
  end;
end;
```

### Delphi Host

The Delphi host manually calls LoadLibrary for the Delphi DLL, retrieves pointers to the functions it needs and calls the DLL using those.

```
procedure InternalSetup;
begin
  FLibrary := LoadLibrary(CLibraryPath);

  GetResource := GetProcAddress(FLibrary, 'GetResource');
  PostResource := GetProcAddress(FLibrary, 'PostResource');
  PutResource := GetProcAddress(FLibrary, 'PutResource');
  DeleteResource := GetProcAddress(FLibrary, 'DeleteResource');
end;
```

Call:
    Result := GetResource(INVALID_URI, {aQueryParams=}'', {out}ResponseBody);

### C# host

The C# host includes the following code to call the DLL

```
    [DllImport("EAConfigurationEngine.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    // Delphi:
    // function GetResource(aURI: string; aQueryParams: string; out aResponseBody: WideString): THTTPStatusCode; stdcall; export;
    private static extern int GetResource(
        string uri,
        string queryParams,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out string responseBody);
```

### Question

As stated above the except block is hit when the host for the DLL is a Delphi executable. However, when a call is made to the Delphi DLL from a C# host, the assertion triggers, the except block is *not reached* (the message isn't logged, instead the uninitialized logger logs an unhandled exception about the assertion), and the C# process dies with the "vshost.exe has stopped working" dialog.

What is causing this to happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Most likely the Delphi host installs sufficient exception handling mechanism to allow the except to work, but that's not in place when the C# host loads the library. I can repro this with the code in the Q right?

Comment: Oh, and you mean Assert(False, ...) I guess

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yeah, Assert(False...: about the only code typed in the browser (replacing the calls to the actual underlying code).

Comment: Also, what are you actually doing in `InitializeDLL`. You do know the perils of doing anything remotely interesting in DllMain?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes I am aware of them. InitializeDLL initializes a DI factory and registers a couple of implementers and classes in there. Doesn't do any external calls. Please note that this whole shebang works perfectly when I remove the "thingy" I added that causes the assertion to trigger.

Comment: So I tried to reproduce the behaviour and failed. Should I expect to be able to reproduce the failure from a 32 bit C# console app?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Can't say at the moment. I am having difficulty getting a simpeler Delphi DLL caller to do what I want. DXE2 not exactly cooperative. I'll try myself with a C# console app. It may well be related to the actual C# host being registered as a windows service. And possibly to that service being run sort of as a normal program based on a command line parameter for debug builds. Will investigate further and post more information as I find it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: But it is good to know that you cannot reproduce it. Narrows it down for me.

Answer (score 2):

Assertions are a particular flavour of exception that require some additional scaffolding and support from the compiler.

If you take a look at the routines involved (in the SysUtils unit) there are a lot of assumptions described such as for example:

```
{ This code is based on the following assumptions:                         }
{  - Our direct caller (AssertErrorHandler) has an EBP frame               }
{  - ErrorStack points to where the return address would be if the         }
{    user program had called System.@RaiseExcept directly                  }
```

This comment is just one of many discussing the assumptions involved with the **ASSERT()** mechanism.

Whether it is this aspect of the assertions implementation in the Delphi compiler that is involved or not, it seems likely to me that these assumptions are not valid when running in a C# host process.  If it is these assumptions that are behind the problem, then raising an exception in the "normal" way may avoid the problem without forcing you to change anything other than the way that you raise the exception itself.

Try replacing your **ASSERT(FALSE, 'Whatever')** with a simple call to raise an **EAssertionFailed** exception directly (i.e. not involving the compiler scaffolding and assumptions that **ASSERT()** invokes).

You can still make the code subject to conditional compilation to achieve the same effect as using the **Enable Assertions** compiler option (compiler option "C"):

```
{$ifopt C+} // only if compiling with assertions enabled
  raise EAssertionFailed.Create('Whatever');
{$endif}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Deltics. Yes, exceptions are handled correctly, assertions aren't. In this case it turned out - haven't yet had time to update the question, needed some sleep :-) - that Delphi XE2 buggy (exception and) assertion handling is to blame. Using XE3 (thanks to @David) the problem wasn't reproducible and when I finally had the correct code firing using the Delphi Host, it died just like the C# host. Replacing the AssertErrorProc and just doing some logging there also remedied the situation, but cannot be deployed as it may functionally change execution paths.

Comment: I actually think that the fundamental problem is a bug in the XE2 x64 compiler's exception handling.

Comment: This answer seems bogus to me. The code that you refer to is not present in XE2. At a guess, I imagine it was changed because XE2 targets x64 and MacOS. Before that the only target was x86. In any case, the assumptions that you refer to, which can be found in the XE code, are satisfied. They are satisfied because `RaiseAssertException` is only called from `AssertErrorHandler`, and it makes those guarantees. The fact that further up the call stack is a C# host is irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is right. The code you mention is not present in XE2 (which I am using). What's more, while the difference between assertions and "normal" exceptions is central to the problem, replacing the AssertErrorProc with a custom one and raising a normal exception (`raise EAssertionFailed.Create();`) in there makes the problem go away. When you look at the `AssertErrorHandler` in `System.SysUtils`, the only difference is that XE2 raises the exception `at ErrorAddr;` All other "special" treatment of assertions remains in place.

Comment: With respect @David, the question did not mention the involvement of XE2 specifically or 64-bit at the time that I answered it (the question actually referenced the XE docs).  Yes, my suggested answer was wrong after all (I was careful to make it clear that it was an 'educated guess', not a verified solution) but calling it "bogus" is unwarranted imho.

Comment: According to the edit history, the XE2 tag was added 2.5 hours before your answer

Comment: Even if this was XE, it would still be bogus. Because you have mis-interpreted those comments. The assumptions listed are all met, in XE and earlier, irrespective of the host. Because that function, the one with the assumptions, is called by the RTL in a way that meets those assumptions.

Comment: The tag may have been present but I didn't scan the tags so didn't notice that.  Comments can't have been /mis/interpreted because they weren't /interpreted/ at all.  If I read Marjan's comment correctly (I am not 100% sure that I am), my suggested answer would have worked even though the reasons for it were not correct.  Call it "bogus" if you like.  Whatever makes you happy.  At least the OP's problem is (seemingly) solved and that's what matters.  :)

Comment: By comment, I mean the comment from the Delphi XE source code that you quoted in your answer. Since the answer is clearly wrong it needs to be fixed or removed. Otherwise it misleads future visitors which is not helpful.